# Why LanguageTool is not working on LibreOffice?

Tags: linux, language, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, grammar

I am using LibreOffice `7.2.2.2`. I have installed LanguageTool `5.4`, then `5.5.1`, but none of them are working. They only add buttons to the toolbar, though they do not react. What would you suggest?

Comment: Try a much earlier version of LanguageTool.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: None of the functionalities of LanguageTool are working. There are buttons on the toolbar that belong to the plugin, but they don't do anything when I click on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my distribution from fedora 35 to debian 11, because fedora 35 failing everywhere. So I got a more intuitive error: `

```
(com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException){{Message="[JavaVirtualMachine]:An unexpected error occurred while searching for Java, 11 ./stoc/source/javavm/javavm.cxx:634", Context = (com.sun.star.uno.XInterface)@0}}
```

Finally, I solved it with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/458240/unable-to-install-languagetool-2-5-extension-for-libreoffice-4-2-on-ubuntu-14-04